# Google Container Engine Subnets

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, isolation

I'm trying to isolate services from one another.

Suppose *ops-human* has a bunch of mysql stores running on Google Container Engine, and *dev-human* has a bunch of node apps running on the same cluster. I do NOT want *dev-human* to be able to access any of *ops-human's* mysql instances in any way.

Simplest solution: put both of these in separate subnets. How do I do such a thing? I'm open to other implementations as well.

Comment: If you put them in different [namespaces](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/namespaces/), is the problem solved?

Comment: @caesarxuchao Namespaces protects against user errors (or just handy configuration) like naming every database just "db". Then the local "db" in that namespace will be found. However if you use a FQDN and you have a flat network like Kubernetes uses, you could access a different resource outside of your namespace. Best is never to have dev and ops running on the same cluster: What if dev produces some new code which pushes out the resources ops requires?

Answer (score 1):

The Kubernetes Network-SIG team has been working on the network isolation issue for a while, and there is an experimental API in kubernetes 1.2 to support this. The basic idea is to provide network policy on a per-namespace basis. A third party network controller can then react to changes to resources and enforces the policy. See the last [blog post](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/04/Kubernetes-Network-Policy-APIs.html) about this topic for the details.

EDIT: This answer is more about the open-source kubernetes, not for GKE specifically.

Answer (score 0):

The NetworkPolicy resource is now available in GKE in alpha clusters ([see latest blog post](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/07/Container-Engine-now-runs-Kubernetes-1-7-to-drive-enterprise-ready-secure-hybrid-workloads.html)).